# How to synchronize database structure but not synchronize data itself in Azure SQL Server？

Tags: sql-server, azure

For example, table T has 3 columns, `id`, `name`, `city`. Now, I add a new column `country` in the testing environment. I want to sync this change (database structure or scheme) instead of executing this script again in the staging and production environments.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably suggest that this isn’t the pattern I would go with. Linking your environments together like that is bound to cause issues.

In the past I have use SQL Server database projects in Visual Studio. These projects allow you to define the structure of your database in SQL syntax and a nice GUI.

[Microsoft article showing how to create one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/how-to-create-a-new-database-project?view=sql-server-ver16)

This means you can put the project into a git repo and then create a deployment pipeline to promote the changes through the environment stages.

The compiled output of the project is called a dacpac and the tooling compares your target db with the structure in the dacpac and makes it match. You can control how it does that through config e.g. don’t drop tables, etc.

[Microsoft article showing deployment steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/sql-azure-dacpac-deployment?view=azure-devops)

Overall this will give you a more refined  control over the database schema.